# Saving panda dataframe to csv changes values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to save a bunch of values in a dataframe to csv but I keep running in the problem that something changes to values **while** saving. Let's have a look at the MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = {
  "value1": [110.589, 222.534, 390.123],
  "value2": [50.111, 40.086, 45.334]
}

df.round(1)
#checkpoint
df.to_csv(some_path)
```

If I debug it and look at the values of df at the step which I marked "checkpoint", thus after rounding, they are like

```
[110.6000, 222.5000, 390.1000],
[50.1000, 40.1000, 45.3000]
```

In reality, my data frame is much larger and when I open the csv after saving, some values (usually in a random block of a couple of dozen rows) have changed! They then look like

```
[110.600000000001, 222.499999999999, 390.099999999999],
[50.099999999999, 40.100000000001, 45.300000000001]
```

So it's always a 0.000000000001 offset from the "real"/rounded values. Does anybody know what's going on here/how I can avoid this?

Comment: Did you try changing the dtype from int/float to str, and then save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical floating point problem. `pandas` gives you the option to define a `float_format`:

```
df.to_csv(some_path, float_format='%.4f')
```

This will force 4 decimals (or actually, does a cut-off at 4 decimals). Note that values will be treated as strings now, so if you set quoting on strings, then these columns are also quoted.